# TYPO3 solr news multiple detail pages

Tags: solr, typo3, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I have 2 different folders with newsrecords: one is used for news and one is for events, they get an own template so they have own detail pages.

SOLR index queue is setup as shown in the extension manual [1](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Backend/IndexQueue.html)

How can I define multiple detail pages for newsrecords in the Solr index queue?
E.g. based on storagePid or category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue can indeed have where conditions:

```
additionalWhereClause = pid = {$events.storagePid}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply define another custom record type.

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
    events < .news
    events {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Your visitors will also benefit from the distinction between events and real news. It's easy to provide a filter for the record types in Solr ("[Facets](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/master/en-us/Frontend/Facets.html#facet-types)"). And you will be able to have different templates for the matches.